# Linear Algebra-Vector Spaces-Sub-Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show by a counter-example that if U+W =U+X for subspaces U,W,X of V, then W need not be equal to X.

Comment: Standard one: $U:=\text{span}\;(1,0)$, the x axis, $W:=\text{span}\;(1,1)$,  $X:=\text{span}\;(0,1)$, the y axis and $V:=\Bbb R^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).